# Unable to drop rows in pandas DataFrame which contain zeros

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, floating

Editing a large dataframe in python. How do you drop entire rows in the dataframe if a specific column's row has the value 0.0?

When I drop the 0.0s in the overall satisfaction column the edits are not displayed in my scatterplot matrix of the large dataframe.

I have tried:

```
filtered_df = filtered_df.drop([('overall_satisfaction'==0)], axis=0)
```

also tried replacing 0.0 with nulls & dropping the nulls:

```
filtered_df = filtered_df.['overall_satisfaction'].replace(0.0, np.nan), axis=0)

filtered_df = filtered_df[filtered_NZ_df['overall_satisfaction'].notnull()]
```

What concept am I missing? Thanks :)

Comment: @coldspeed You fixed it!! Thank you sooo much!
I'm new to this site, I'll definitely be back.  =D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems like your values are small enough to be represented as zeros, but are not actually zeros. This usually happens when calculations result in vanishing gradients (really small numbers that approach zero, but are not quite zero), so equality comparisons do not give you the result you're looking for.

In cases like this, numpy has a handy function called `isclose` that lets you test whether a number is close enough to another number within a certain tolerance.

In your case, doing

```
df = df[~np.isclose(df['overall_satisfaction'], 0)]
```

Seems to work.